# harbor: login required for pulling open image

Tags: docker, harbor

I'm trying to access a private docker registry served by Harbor. When logged out, pulling `n.n.n.n/some_path/some_image:some_tag` will result in **image not found** error message. The image is not private. When I login with

```
`docker login -u user -p pass n.n.n.n`
```

pulling works fine.

I think this is wrong (or is it?). Did I configure the Harbor server incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you configured your Harbor server I would say correctly.

This is the error message docker say when an image is private. In docker hub it happens in the same way.

So find the way to unprotect your image in Harbor.

I know that in the official registry container it is not possible. You can protect the entire registry or not.

**Update**

Looks like in Harbor you need to have an account even for public projects. Check if you have disabled Anonymous access.

Comment: I double checked and `some_path` correspond to a public project. So I'm still puzzled.

Comment: As I can see in harbor, you must be logged to access even the public projects. https://github.com/vmware/harbor/issues/866. So your users need to register in your portal to have access to your public image